# Resample by some timeframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like:

```
Timestamp            Sold
10.01.2017 10:00:20  10
10.01.2017 10:01:55  20
10.01.2017 11:02:11  15
11.01.2017 11:04:30  10
11.01.2017 11:15:35  35
12.01.2017 10:02:01  22
```

How to resample it by hour. Ordinary resample resamples by all hours from first row to last. But what I need is to make timeframe (10-11) and resample it within this timeframe.

Last df should be like this:

```
Timestamp            Sold
10.01.2017 10:00:00  30
10.01.2017 11:00:00  15
11.01.2017 10:00:00  NAN
11.01.2017 11:00:00  45
12.01.2017 10:00:00  22
12.01.2017 11:00:00  NAN
```

Comment: What did the documentation say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
df_out = df.groupby(df.Timestamp.dt.floor('H')).sum()
df_out.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
            Timestamp  Sold
0 2017-10-01 10:00:00    30
1 2017-10-01 11:00:00    15
2 2017-11-01 11:00:00    45
3 2017-12-01 10:00:00    22
```